# on App resume beaconmanager fails to detect beacon using Android Beacon Library

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, beacon

First time I run the app beacon monitoring and ranging is working fine. But the second time I lanuch the app i.e after calling onResume it is only showing following and no more calls to didRangeBeaconsInRegion : I am guessing it is because of beaconManager instance is not properly destroyed or something in calls to onDestroy. However according to the library example I tried unbinding in onPause() with no success. Any idea ?

```
I/MonitoringActivity: I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: 0
2020-07-15 18:41:40.776 9657-9657/com.something.beacon I/MonitoringActivity: I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: 0
2020-07-15 18:41:40.824 9657-9657/com.something.beacon I/MonitoringActivity: I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: 1


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION = 2;

ListView beaconList;
protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
private BeaconManager beaconManager;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference beaconDBRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    //Firebase database setup
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    beaconDBRef = database.getReference().child("messages");

    beaconList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.beacon_list);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: is called");

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    // Detect the main identifier (UID) frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));

    // Detect the telemetry (TLM) frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));

    // Detect the URL frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT));

    beaconManager.bind(this);

    verifyBluetooth();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (!this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)) {
                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setTitle("This app needs background location access");
                        builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons in the background.");
                        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                            @TargetApi(23)
                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
                            }

                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                    else {
                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                        builder.setMessage("Since background location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons in the background.  Please go to Settings -> Applications -> Permissions and grant background location access to this app.");
                        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            }

                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
            else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons.  Please go to Settings -> Applications -> Permissions and grant location access to this app.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }

                });
                builder.show();
            }

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}

long tempTime = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
long callInterval = 10000;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "fine location permission granted");
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover nearby devices.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }

                });
                builder.show();
            }
            return;
        }
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "background location permission granted");
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                builder.setMessage("Since background location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover devices when in the background.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }

                });
                builder.show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
private void verifyBluetooth() {

    try {
        if (!BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).checkAvailability()) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Bluetooth not enabled");
            builder.setMessage("Please enable bluetooth in settings and restart this application.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    //finish();
                    //System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Bluetooth LE not available");
        builder.setMessage("Sorry, this device does not support Bluetooth LE.");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                //finish();
                //System.exit(0);
            }

        });
        builder.show();

    }

}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    // Set the two identifiers below to null to detect any beacon regardless of identifiers
    Identifier myBeaconNamespaceId = Identifier.parse("0x2F234454F4911BA9FFA6");
    final Identifier myBeaconInstanceId = Identifier.parse("0x000000000001");

    beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
    beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();

    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");

            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "didEnterRegion");
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");

            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "didExitRegion");
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
        }
    });


    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            for(Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
                String beaconInfo = "Namespace id: " + oneBeacon.getId1() + "\nInstance Id: " + oneBeacon.getId2();
                Log.d(TAG, beaconInfo);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, beaconInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Write to database every 10 seconds
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(currentTime > tempTime + callInterval){

                    BeaconModel beaconModel = new BeaconModel();

                    beaconModel.setBeaconName(oneBeacon.getId2().toString());
                    beaconModel.setDistance(oneBeacon.getDistance());
                    beaconModel.setMessage("this is a nice message");

                    beaconDBRef.child(beaconModel.getBeaconName()).setValue(beaconModel);
                    //beaconDBRef.push().setValue("beacon detected! - " + oneBeacon.getId2());
                    tempTime = currentTime;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    try {

        Identifier myBeaconNamespaceId1 = Identifier.parse("0xedd1ebeac04e5defa017");
        Identifier myBeaconInstanceId1 = Identifier.parse("0x0e32fea91b13");
        Identifier myBeaconInstanceId2 = Identifier.parse("0xa9937b420872");

        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", myBeaconNamespaceId1, myBeaconInstanceId1, null));
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId2", myBeaconNamespaceId1, myBeaconInstanceId2, null));
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId3", null, null, null));

    } catch (RemoteException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: code updated please check.

Comment: What happens if you move the unbind to on pause?  This works in the library reference app.  You might try adding more log statements in each method do you can follow what is happening  when the activity is restarted.

Comment: I tried moving `unbind` in `onPause`, still the same. i did some logging : when the activity is restarted `onCreate` is called always so `beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);` is called always.. whenever i clear storage and uninstall the app and reinstall again, it definitely works again on the first run!